# SQL Transaction log

Tags: sql, transaction-log

How do I get rid of this massive (110GB) LDF file?
I have changed the recovery method to simple, we will never want to restore to a specific point in time so we do not need the full method.
The LDF file is still there! I have done a backup of the database but looking at the backup file size this seems to have just backed up the MDF.
The LDF remains!

Comment: You have a database with 100+ GBs of transaction log let alone data, but no DBA on staff? A DBA would have been able to solve this "problem" without Google and StackOverflow.

Comment: @JohnGaughan To be fair, I've worked at multiple places without DBAs that had transaction logs that big (partially *because* they didn't have DBAs...)

Answer (score -2):

You didn't mention Version of SQL Server. This works on 2005 (i'm not sure about 2008 and superior). First do a FULL Backup. Then try this:

```
CHECKPOINT
Backup Log myDatabase WITH Truncate_Only
```

After that, right click de DB -> Tasks -> Reduce -> Database.

That should do it. Hope this helped.